# Pass more arguments with sender and e?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, .net

I have a function in the c# code that looks like:

```
protected void UploadFile(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
blah blah blah
}
```

and this function will upload file to the server.

i call to the function like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload!" OnClick="UploadFile"/>
```

i want to pass another argument to the function, and its will be the name of the file.

but i tried to add it in the `UploadFile` and its not work, how can i do it? thanks.

Comment: where do you get the file name from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an **event** attached to your `Button`. You shouldn't call the event like a method, instead you can extract the method logic to a separate method and then call that method with your parameter. As far as accessing the `FileName` is concerned, you can access that from your File TextBox (probably you are using one)

```
protected void UploadFile(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
UploadFileMethod(yourFileTextBox.Text);
}

private void UploadFileMethod(string FileName)
{
 //upload logic
}
```

and to call it from somewhere else.

```
UploadFileMethod("NewFileName");
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems strange, as you do not need to send file name to the `UploadFile` function. You can just use the filename in the `UploadFile` function itself.

```
protected void UploadFile(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
   // var file = ......
}
```

On the otherhand, if you get the filename from another control, you can just get the filename from this control in the `UploadFile` function.

```
protected void UploadFile(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
   var file = textboxX.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass many parameters you should implement your own class like this:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(params object[] args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }

    public object[] Args { get; set; }
}
```

Your event will be in this form:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

To raise your event:

```
MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(1, "information"));
```